# save on cost when using Amazon EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, optimization, amazon-ec2, disk, amazon-ebs

Seeing that Amazon has priced the usage of EBS as:

> $0.10 per GB-month of provisioned storage; $0.10 per 1 million I/O requests

Even though the value is in millions, I/O request add up pretty quickly 
... I was wondering if there are any best practices for reducing I/O requests out there.
E.g. Use an instance with more than enough RAM required for your app.. Tweak some OS level parameters.. dont do a 'sync' every couple of minutes :) .... etc.

Comment: This is kind of a broad question; can you add some details on what your app does with regard to I/O, file system and database usage ?

Comment: Good point! However, I'm not looking at a particular app, but general practices to keep in mind when dealing with EBS.

Comment: Inasmuch as this is a request for OS-level optimization suggestions, it might be better placed at ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the general advice about avoiding premature **micro**optimizations should probably apply here.  Think first about making sure you are using the PaaS architecture appropriately, and tweak parameters once you have data.  Repost a more specific question (as gareth said).

But I do have one specific optimization, since you asked: add a ramdisk to your linux machines, so that temporary files don't touch storage:

```
echo "none /tmp/ tmpfs defaults 0 0" >>/etc/fstab
```

and use `vmstat -Sm 5` to watch how much IO is being done.

Comment: Or in cases where RAM is not plentiful, you can use the local instance storage (make sure you mount it) for /tmp.
The local instance store only persists during the life of the instance. There is no IOPS cost associated with this type of storage.

Comment: @Thangaraj on Micro instances (the once that come with the free tier), you do not have local storage, only EBS. Yet, the ramdisk trick should still work, right?